# Combinatorics, dividing 11 distinct books among 3 people?

Tags: combinatorics

So the problem at hand is how many ways can 11 distinct books be assigned to person A, B, C when A must have 6 books, B must have 3 books and C must have 2 books.

The solution is ${{11}\choose{6}} * {{5}\choose{3}} * {{2}\choose{2}}$

This basically means A chooses 6 then B chooses 3 then C chooses 2.
But why does A have to choose first, why cannot we have B chooses its 3, then C chooses its 2 and A chooses the remaining. This would be the same as the expression above.
So shouldnt the expression above be multiplied by the way in which A, B,C should choose first. I dont see how it would be overcounting.

If you have A,B,C selecting in that order and then C,A,B selecting in that order wouldnt you get different combinations.

Comment: The order should not matter, since it only matters which books A/B/C ends up with. If C picks first and gets books 1,2 and B picks 3-5, and A gets 6-11, it's the same as if they picked in a different order and ended up with the same books

Answer (score 2):

Note that ${11 \choose 6}*{5 \choose 3}*{2 \choose 2}=\frac{11!*5!*2!}{6!*5!*3!*2!*2!}$. If instead the order of choice went B,C,A we'd have:

${11 \choose 3}*{8 \choose 2}*{6 \choose 6}=\frac{11!*8!*6!}{3!*8!*2!*6!*6!}$

Note how both expressions cancel to $\frac{11!}{6!*3!*2!}$ as this is the number of ways to organise the 11 books, divided by the number of ways to organise the 6,3 and 2 books that A,B,C each get. This doesn't depend on which order they are taken, this depends on what order the end up in - and this is what we are trying to count.

Comment: Yes, this is correct. What we end up with is the _multinomial coefficient_ $\binom{11}{2,3,6}$, or $(2,3,6)!$ if you prefer Wolfram notation.