# Suppose we have 15 different books, And we want these books to be split between 3 people.

Tags: permutations, combinations

Suppose we have 15 different books, And we want these books to be split between 3 people.

How many ways are there such that  each person will have exactly five books?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind

Comment: @Bram28 - Is this answer $\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
   {15}  \\
   5  \\
\end{array}} \right)\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
   {10}  \\
   5  \\
\end{array}} \right)\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
   5  \\
   5  \\
\end{array}} \right) \times 3!$ true?

Comment: @Bram28 - Thanks.

Comment: @Bram28 - But I believe the answer wrong because Let "we have 3 different books, And we want these books to be split between 3 people.

How many ways are there such that each person will have exactly one book"?  Is it true that $\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
   3  \\
   1  \\
\end{array}} \right)\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
   2  \\
   1  \\
\end{array}} \right)\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
   1  \\
   1  \\
\end{array}} \right) \times 3!$

Comment: @H.S you are right and I was wrong! I was confused: when you divide n into k otherwise undifferentiated groups you have to divide the block of choose terms by k! (Indeed, there is exactly 1 way to divide 3 books into 3 books of 1) ... but of course that does not mean that you need to multiply by k! the block of choose terms when you do differentiate the groups. Whoops, my mistake!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are $\binom{15}{5,5,5} = \frac{15!}{5!5!5!}$ ways to split 15 objects into 3 subsets of 5 elements each. (An alternative notation for [multinomial coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem) is $(5,5,5)!$, as used by [Wolfram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MultinomialCoefficient.html))

So, the correct answer is $$\binom{15}{5}\binom{10}{5}\binom{5}{5}=\binom{15}{5,5,5}=\frac{1307674368000}{120^{3}}=756756$$

If you now multiply by the number of permutations of the three people, $3!$, you overcount, because you are distinguishing between the cases when, say, *Alice* gets books $b_1,b_2,b_3,b_4,b_5$ as the first person and the cases when she gets exactly the same books as the second person. As H.S correctly pointed out in a comment to another answer, if you split three books evenly among three people, you get $\binom{3}{1,1,1} = 6$ ways and not $\binom{3}{1,1,1}\cdot3!=36$ ways. What matters is who receives which books, not the order in which the books are distributed.

See also [this similar question.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1996032/combinatorics-dividing-11-distinct-books-among-3-people)

Comment: Yes, you are right! :)